# How to revert to previous commit after pull without losing previous changes?

Tags: linux, github

I tested the changes on local side with my newly implemented code, and everything worked fine.  Once I committed the changes and pushed those changes to GitHub, I pulled from that repository within my server which is on Linux. Rebuilding the server failed as it ran into an error.

How do I revert back to my previous pull without losing these changes that I just pulled?

Answer (score 1):

You can move all the changes since the last commit you want back to the staging area by executing

`git reset HEAD~k --soft`

where `k` is the number of commits since the commit you want
(use `git log` and pick out a specific commit, and then use its hash instead of `HEAD~k` if you don't want to count).

You may then do whatever you want with them. For example:

- stash them using `git stash`
- commit them on another branch and push it, so you can pull them on your local workstation and continue working on them:

  by executing

  ```
  git checkout -b newBranch
  git commit
  git push
  ```

  on your server, and finally `git pull` on your local workstation.
  (though you should still have them on your local workstation anyways, at least until you pull)

Or, use [Allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226345/12096180) if you don't want to change the current branch, and just want to build a working version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

- You can get commit history by

```
git log
```

- And then, you can go back to the specific commit by using

```
git checkout 3ef0d...
```